# Schedule - Run a job until a certain time Python

Tags: python, task, schedule

Hello and thank you in advance. I am trying to write simple code to run a function for a specified duration. I basically copied this verbatim from schedule module docs (just changed units) but for some reason cannot get it to work.

```
import schedule
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time

def job():
    print('Hello World')

schedule.every(5).seconds.until(timedelta(seconds=20)).do(job)
```

I am not getting any errors, but the console will not print 'Hello World'. It has to be something simple but I cannot figure it out as I am very new at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using schedule, you will need a while loop to keep the program running. Modify your code like this will solve the issue.

```
import schedule
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time
import time


def job():
    print('Hello World')


schedule.every(5).seconds.until(timedelta(seconds=20)).do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```